# Jquery code to execute a code every 3 minutes

Tags: jquery

On the button click function i have to execute a code segment in every 3 minutes.
here is the code am using.

```
$('#rBtn').click(function() {
```

// i have to execute  below code to every 3 minutes

```
      $.get('/getTests', function (jobs) {
    seljobs = jobs;
    var i = 0
    jobs.forEach(function (n) {
      html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + n.names + '</option>';
      i++;
    });
    $('#jobSel').html(html);
  });       

  });
```

I tried this way.

```
$('#rBtn').click(function() {
 gettests();
  });
```

i used `setTimeout` as follows but it is not working.in every 3 minutes.

```
 function gettests(){

 setTimeout(gettests,300000);
    $.get('/getTests', function (jobs) {
        seljobs = jobs;
        var i = 0
        jobs.forEach(function (n) {
          html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + n.names + '</option>';
          i++;
        });
        $('#jobSel').html(html);
      });  

}
```

Comment: 300000 is every 5 minutes.... 3 mins is 180000 = 3 X 60 seconds * 1000 ms

Comment: setTimeout(gettests,300000); should be outside function gettests() and 3 mins are 180000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like this

```
function gettests() {
    $.get('/getTests', function(jobs) {
        seljobs = jobs;
        var i = 0;
        jobs.forEach(function(n) {
            html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + n.names + '</option>';
            i++;
        });
        $('#jobSel').html(html);
    });
}
setTimeout(gettests, 180000);
```

The `setTimeout` should be outside of the function.`setTimeout` only execute the function once

If you want to execute it on every 3minute then use `setInterval()`

```
function gettests() {
    $.get('/getTests', function(jobs) {
        seljobs = jobs;
        var i = 0;
        jobs.forEach(function(n) {
            html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + n.names + '</option>';
            i++;
        });
        $('#jobSel').html(html);
    });
}
var interv=setInterval(gettests, 180000)
```

For stop use `clearInterval()`

```
clearInterval(interv);
```

The ID value returned by `setInterval()` is used as the parameter for the `clearInterval()` method.

Comment: is this cod ewill excute every 3 mintes...it is wirking at first time not every 3 minutes right?

Comment: for that use `setInterval(gettests, 180000)`;

Comment: for stoping the interval what shoud i do?